# Modern equivalent for "arrah", or for its Irish version, "yarrah"

Tags: meaning, interjections, late-modern-english

I was reading an article on dialect discourse markers, and I came across one, namely *"arrah"*, the meaning of which I couldn't fully understand. It was said that it is in some sort a **"defensive" discourse marker**, used in tense conversations, especially when there is a difference in social status between the speakers. Below is the example, provided in [the article](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pragmatic_Markers_Discourse_Markers_and/9IM6DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=arrah+definition&pg=PA409&printsec=frontcover), it actually contains the Irish version of *"arrah"* - *"yarrah"*, but it doesn't really matter. Could you please suggest an equivalent for *"arrah"*, which can be used nowadays?

> "Dan Shiel, you little starved-looking spalpeen, will you come up to your Illocution? - and a purty figure you cut at it, wid a voice like a penny thrumpet, Dan! Well, what speech have you got now, Dan, ma bouchal? Is it, 'Romans, counthry, and lovers?'"
>
> "No shir; **yarrah**, didn't I spake that speech before? 'tis wan, masther, that I'm afther Pennen' myself."
>
> [Stories from Carleton, 1889](https://books.google.com/books?id=ULQsAAAAYAAJ&newbks=0&dq=%22no%20shir%22%20yarrah&pg=PA290&source=bookclip&ci=190%2C1066%2C761%2C172)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is present in most dictionaries which define arrah as an expression of excitement.

***[arrah](https://www.lexico.com/definition/arrah)*** [ ar-uh ]

Irish

> Expressing excitement or strong emotion.
>
> - ‘‘Arrah, don't be talking nonsense,’ Elmer exclaimed’
>
> Etymology - Late 17th century from Irish *ara, arú.*

(Lexico.com)

[arrah](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrah) (interjection)

> Irish
>   —used to express surprise or excitement.

(M-W)

[The daily edge](https://www.dailyedge.ie/ara-look-at-the-poor-craythur-a-dictionary-of-odd-irish-words-638807-Oct2012/) website suggests the following usage:

> ***[“Ara“](https://www.dailyedge.ie/ara-look-at-the-poor-craythur-a-dictionary-of-odd-irish-words-638807-Oct2012/)***
>   - Ara is used to give an indication that you’re really not too fussed about something. It can also be used to start pretty much any sentence:
>
> - *Ara I might go. I might not.*
>
> ***“Ara Musha“***
>   - When ara is used in conjunction with musha then it means something else entirely. It’s a term of endearment or affection:
>
> - *Ara musha you poor craythur, you’ll be grand.*